# MySQL statement to get a column's value from all rows where another column's value = a specified value

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Could someone please show me a MySQL statement that will get the value of column *student*, in all rows where the value of column *teacher* is equal to charles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this info is in the same table, then

```
select student from table_name where teacher = 'charles'
```

If you have 3 tables like it should be (teachers, students and the M:N table for teachers_students), please comment as then you'd need a join.